# how to set superscript and subscript at the same place in qtextedit

Tags: qt, subscript, superscript

I want to show the superscript and subscript at the same place.like this:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].